# Reading child element as field value from XML

Tags: java, xml, cdata, xstream

I have the following xml structure

```
<insert tableName="TABLE_NAME">
  <column name="NAME" value="VALUE"/>
</insert>
```

but it can appear in the following way as well in case the value is written in CDATA

```
<insert tableName="TABLE_NAME">
  <column name="NAME"><![CDATA[Something here]]></column> 
</insert>
```

Java POJO look like this:

```
@XStreamAlias("Resources")
public class Resources {

    @XStreamAlias("column")
    class Column {
        String name;
        String value;
    }

    @XStreamAlias("insert")
    class Insert {
        @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "column")
        List<Column> column=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "insert")
    public List<Insert> insert = new ArrayList();
}
```

How can I read the CDATA child element as the column's value attribute?